# What's the usual approach here for multiple table columns with one controller's view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a list of `Something`...

So I create a controller method called `List` and it returns `View("List", IEnumerable<Something>)`...

That view is basically a for loop over the objects creating a table. Cool so far.

---

In another view I may want the same table with an extra column allowing a user to checkbox which Somethings he is interested in doing something with.

I have to amend the previous controller like so:

```
// Need method created
IEnumerable<Something> PrepareData()
{
    // Does some calls to repositories.. returns data with pagination and all that crap applied
}

ActionResult List()
{
    IEnumerable<Something> somethings = PrepareData();
    return View("_List", somethings);
}
```

so I do not have to repeat the code for my other controller that I now seem to need to create:

```
ActionResult ListWithCheckbox()
{
    IEnumerable<Something> somethings = PrepareData();
    return View("_ListWithCheckbox", somethings);
}
```

And now I need two separate views with very similar code in, and this is the bit which sucks... and i'm not sure a simple `if` statement on some kind of checkbox bool passed to the view is the best idea?

**List.cshtml (Pseudo)**

```
<table>
    for( items )
    {
        <tr><td>item.Name</td></tr>
    }
</table>
```

**ListWithCheckbox.cshtml (Pseudo)**

```
<table>
    for( items )
    {
        <tr>
            <td><checkbox></td>
            <td>item.Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Please imagine there's quite a bit more to this view, so repeating that code in 2 places is a bit of a noob idea.

What do you guys normally do when you want a table of items to be multi functional?

Comment: What you could do is create a viewmodel that contains a list of somethings and a bool called showCheckboxes or something similar.
Depending on this bool you let your View show the checkboxes or not.

Comment: Okay, so... that's actually helpful to know that you too are thinking of this way. I wonder if a few more would also agree with this... vindication etc.

Comment: "What do you guys normally do when you want a table of items to be multi functional?" I normally extract a [Partial View](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/617361/Partial-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-4) IF the code is similar enough AND I expect both versions of the view to evolve together (e.g. I want changes to HTML to affect both pages). If they are similar, but different enough, or will likely not be similar in the future, sometimes repeating yourself (a little) is best. I would suggest starting with two copies of the similar code first though, then refactor; generalizing first is usually bad.

Comment: It depends actually, I personally don't think there is anything wrong with similar views as long as there is a very clear difference in functionality. e.g. this grid is for editing, this one for deleting. My main concern is to keep my code maintainable and if you think this would be the case when you merge these two views then I don't see a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Something> Somethings { get; set; }
    public bool ShowCheckboxes { get; set; }
}
```

and then have your controller action take a boolean parameter:

```
public ActionResult List(bool showCheckboxes)
{
    var model = new MyViewModel();
    model.Somethings = PrepareData();
    model.ShowCheckboxes = showCheckboxes;
    return View("_List", model);
}
```

and then inside your view:

```
@model MyViewModel
...
<table>
    foreach(var item in Model.Somethings)
    {
        <tr>
            @if (Model.ShowCheckboxes)
            {
                <td><checkbox></td>
            }
            <td>item.Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Now you could use `/somecontroller/list` and `/somecontroller/list?showcheckboxes=true`.

Comment: I used this to some extent... so thanks for submitting an actual answer.